Error: Unexpected value 'StoreRootModule' imported by the module 'CoreModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation
I updated my Angular version from 15 to 16. The compiler did not give any errors, but the browser console displayed this error:

core.module.ts
imports: [
 CommonModule,
 StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers, {
   metaReducers: [storageMetaReducer]
 }),
 EffectsModule.forRoot(appEffects),
 StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({ stateKey: 'router' }),
 !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : []
]
})```

any one can help me sove this issue

I need to solve this issue

I faced the same error when I upgraded my Angular to v16.
It was all about NgRx > ngrx/store, update the plugin to v16 by:
ng update @ngrx/store@16

Ref: https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v16
